# Java ImageIcon unkown source

Tags: java, image

This is driving me up a wall. In java, I'm trying to get an image in a JOptionPane, but it just gives me an exception each time telling me it cant find the image. Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at mad.madster.passbook.gui.GUILauncher.main(GUILauncher.java:67)
```

Here is the code for it:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(GUILauncher.class.getResource("/src/Bookimg.png"));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is your first time "
                + "opening Passbook. You will "
                + "need to create a master password to login to "
                + "Passbook.", "test", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

Ive tried grabbing the image from a res folder I made, directly from my computer, and even via website. Nothing works, same exception.

Comment: `getResource("/Bookimg.png"));` + case-sensitive name

Comment: Image returns null. Ive tried what they are saying on that question.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. The only reason you are facing issues is the location or the name of your image. Place it along with your Java class and instead of "/src/Bookimg.png" use getResource("Bookimg.png"), or better place it in an "images" folder at the same level as the package of the class and getResource("/images/Booking.png");